# Write to file descriptor 3 in node

Tags: node.js, file-descriptor

`console.log` uses `process.stdout.write` to write to file descriptor (fd) 1

and

`console.error` uses `process.stderr.write` to write to file descriptor (fd) 2

How can I create a new file descriptor 3? and write to that?

Update: using `net`

```
import net from 'net'

const example = new net.Socket({ fd: 3, writable: true })

const buffBaby = Buffer.from('meow', 'utf8')

example.write(buffBaby)
```

I get this error:

> Error: ENOTTY: inappropriate ioctl for device, uv_pipe_open

And I've tried this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const fd3 = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 3});
fd3.write("Hello to FD 3!\n");
```

> Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, write

Comment: fd 3 is not one of the well known fds that a processes inherit from the parent process. You have to open a file or dup existing fd.  Then the OS will assign a lowest available number, and it's possibly 3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your process already has such an FD in mind, otherwise you'd be asking how to write to a file or socket and not an FD. Assuming so, this will work:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fd3 = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 3});
fd3.write("Hello to FD 3!\n");
```

That creates a new stream associated with FD 3, just as `process.stdout` is associated with FD 1 and `process.stderr` is associated with FD 2.

I'm assuming your FD is blocking (the default for FDs in Linux). If it's non-blocking for some reason, then you'd need to either change it back to blocking or use [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options) instead.

If you run that code when you didn't give it an FD to write to, then something bad like this will probably happen:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, write
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:96:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -22,
  code: 'EINVAL',
  syscall: 'write'
}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Or maybe this:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, close
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:96:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -9,
  code: 'EBADF',
  syscall: 'close'
}
```

If you actually do want to open the FD from node, then you can use any ordinary means of opening a file to do that. You can't guarantee FD 3 in that case, though, since there's a good chance that something internal to Node is already using FD 3, and you can't just steal it out from under it.

Comment: I don't believe I quite have a working knowledge of how FD's work. What I'm expecting is NOT to create a file (possibly create a temp file if required) and have the command "output" an arbitrary string accessible via command pipe. eg `node ./index.js | loop-file-descriptor`

Comment: I've tried `net` and i'm getting an error update in question.

Comment: @ThomasReggi If you're using bash's `|`, that's always FD 1, so just use what's already there for it.

Answer (score 1):

this question stopped me, as I have not seen any POSIX or otherwise syscall that you can choose what fd number you want to create, such as [socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) - please correct me if am wrong, I wanted to clarify on the net.Socket options from [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options) and it says:

> fd: (number) If specified, wrap around an existing socket with the given file descriptor, otherwise a new socket will be created.

this means that it doesn't create the socket on a fd of your choice, instead, it reuse an existing one, I assume to avoid creating a new connection for performance reasons or share a connection with other thread or consumer.

finally, please be aware that fd number is unique per process domain, or (process control block), that being said, creation of fd is incremental starting from 3 as 0, 1 and 2 are reserved, based on that, you can anticipate an fd number if you know for sure the correct sequence of open connections as every open connection or socket or file will create one - if you don't close them

Comment: There is a syscall to choose an FD indirectly: [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html). First use `open`/etc. just to get some FD, then do `dup2(fd_from_open, fd_number_you_want);` and `close(fd_from_open);` However, it's dangerous to do so unless you're sure the FD number you want isn't already in use by the Node runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I think this one completely slipped off my mind, it's very true you can set an fd that will be created in dup2, but like you said its indirectly as it's never intended to use it like so, and highly unrecommended.