# communicating with a spawn() child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a child process using `spawn()` with it's own terminal

parent.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log('started parent process...'); //this should be printed in the parent terminal

const child = spawn('start node', [`child.js`], {
    cwd:__dirname,
    shell: true,
    stdio: [null, null, null, 'pipe']
});

const Name = 'general kenobi';

child.stdio[3].write(Name);

child.stdio[3].on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('data=>', data.toString());
    child.kill();
});
```

child.js:

```
console.log('started child process...');

(async()=>{
    await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,3000));

    try{
        let net = require('net');
        let pipe = new net.Socket({ fd: 3 });

        pipe.on('data',(data)=>{
            pipe.write(`hello there ${data}`);
        });
    }catch(err){console.log(err)}
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
})();
```

the expected data should be `data=> hello there general kenobi` but it gives this error in the child terminal

> ```
>  throw new ERR_INVALID_FD_TYPE(type);
>   ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_FD_TYPE]: Unsupported fd type: UNKNOWN
>     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
>     at createHandle (node:net:152:9)
>     at new Socket (node:net:340:20)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\parent.js:4:12)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
>   code: 'ERR_INVALID_FD_TYPE'
> }
> ```

I couldn't find many references so I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o8B3L0-d9c) as a guide

(please try to avoid a 3rd party package while answering)

Comment: Have you read https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio? Why do you want to use a fourth pipe instead of the standard ones?

Comment: @Bergi my understanding is that `console.log()` is the same as `process.stdout.write()` hence if I was to log() something in the child terminal it would also be sent as data to the parent

Comment: Ah, yes, so you want to ignore `console.log`s from the child process?

Comment: Related (but without accepted answer): [Write to file descriptor 3 in node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61433529/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly, do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Dunno, from what I can tell your code should work. (Apart from `process.stdio[3]` not being available in the child, I assume you meant `pipe`). Only thing I could find is that [it might not work on Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/345)?

Comment: @Bergi I fixed the `process.stdio[3]` it take a look

Comment: Thanks, but I fear that issue was not relevant, the exception was thrown before that line was reached :-)

Comment: @Bergi if it helps I've made a working version https://justpaste.it/4v4hu but the child doesn't open in a separate terminal and hence you cannot `console.log()` anything from the child

Comment: I think you are not passing the option correctly. you are missing `[]` change to `let pipe = new net.Socket([{ fd: 3 }]);`

Comment: @Snake_py [`net.Socket` does not take an array but an object](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netsocket) as the first parameter

Comment: @Snake_py i tired that and now it's not giving an err in catch but none the less it's not working either but I agree with Bergi I don't think you can pass an array according to the docs

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do will work. You're spawning "start", which is a separate command from Node itself. Does it pass stdin/stdout and other fds? It doesn't appear so. You may not be able to achieve bi-directional communication this way - you may need to look for another way, such as network sockets over localhost.

Comment: @RobertKawecki Oh, good call, I missed that! You might as well make it an answer to use `node` instead of `start node`

Comment: @RobertKawecki (appologies for the late response) I had a feeling `start` would be the problem but my ultimate aim is just to spawn a process in a new terminal so I can log() the 2 processes separately and I'm not sure but network sockets seem like overkill, is there some other method(s) I can look into?

Comment: @cakelover is the point just to have them run in separate terminals for logging purposes or do you actually need the IPC channel/Socket to let the processes communicate with eachother?

Comment: @NikolaOlaric I need them to communicate with each other

Answer (score 2):

Remove `shell: true` and change command to 'node' in `parent.js` file.

```
const child = spawn('node', [`child.js`], {
cwd:__dirname,
stdio: [null, null, null, 'pipe']
});
```

Instead of using spawn itself, while adding `shell: true`, spawn will use [shell of your system](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) to run that command. generally, I suggest use pure spawn without using shell. The risk will reduce without touching shell directly and problem of piping data.

Comment: how does this open a new terminal? have you read the comments? : )

Comment: @cakelover generally `child_processs` (spawn, ...) open new `shell` in your system. I believe messaging in [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) should be helpful instead of piping data on spawn. Cluster messaging used standard IPC messaging and is so easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, as others mentioned in the comments, `'start node'` should be just `'node'`.
I compared the video you linked and found out if you change `'node'` (the `spawn` argument) to `'process.execPath'` it magically works!

parent.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log('started parent process...'); //this should be printed in the parent terminal

const child = spawn(process.execPath, [`child.js`], {
    //cwd:__dirname,
    //shell: true,
    stdio: [null, null, null, 'pipe']
});

const Name = 'general kenobi';

child.stdio[3].write(Name);

child.stdio[3].on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('data=>', data.toString());
    child.kill();
});
```

I'm not currently sure why this is happening?? It might just be a bug I guess! For now, I thought maybe only the fix helps you.

If you log the `process.execPath` and as It was mentioned in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processexecpath), it returns the absolute path to node and resolves all symbolic links too. This might be the problem with spawn.

Also if you use `shell: true` in the options, the child process doesn't get killed. I don't know if it's expected behaviour for you or not.

**Update:**

The problem in my ubuntu was because of using node from snap packages, and it's probably a bug from snap trying to sandbox the process.

I have opened a topic in [snapcraft](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/node-js-spawn-function/27541) and it's probably a known bug with snaps about file descriptor. You can read more about workarounds and the bug in the link.

**Update 2:**

Another method to achieve using spawning the message on second command line.

parent.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log('started parent process...');

const child = spawn('node', ['child.js'], {
  cwd: __dirname,
  stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc'],
});

const Name = 'general kenobi';

child.send(Name);
child.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log('data=>', data);
  // child.kill();
});
```

child.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

console.log('started child process...');

process.on('message', (data) => {
  process.send(`hello there ${data}`);
  const cmd = spawn('start', ['cmd.exe', '/k', `echo hello there ${data}`], {
    cwd: __dirname,
    shell: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: well I really don't see how this answers the question, my ultimate aim is to start a child spawn process in a new terminal **while** still being able to communicate with the parent process and `start` wasn't going to work but I wanted to give a sense of what I needed in the question

Comment: @cakelover Are you using Node from snap packages? And if yes, you can install Node from other [sources](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/), or use the workaround I mentioned in the link. You can't do what you want if you are using snaps currently, because it's a bug!

Comment: no I'm not using snap packages plus I'm on windows

Comment: @cakelover using `process.execPath` didn't solve the problem?

Comment: could u add some code so I can understand what you're trying to say better? did you mean I should `const child = spawn(process.execPath)`?

Comment: @cakelover Yeah sorry if my answer was confusing, I added the `parent.js`. And yes the code that you mentioned is correct.

Comment: I have also tested it on windows, and it works fine.

Comment: does the child process open in a new terminal?

Comment: no it doesn't spawn new terminal, but it shows the child process outputs in parent process. And it also prints data=> hello there general kenobi. The shell option only executes in a shell or cmd environment, this means in windows it only executes with some more parameters, you can read what it does in more details [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).

Comment: the entire point of this question was so that the child process would open in a new terminal

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this? Maybe I can find a better solution if you give me more details. You only want to print in the new terminal for once? or you want to send multiple messages after?

Comment: @cakelover I have also updated the answer with another method that might be what you needed.

Comment: well I've tried update2 before but I need to communicate it with instead of sending the message only once, the goal is to open a child process in a new terminal but still be  able to communicate with the parent process